# Create sequence overview from rows

Tags: r, sequence

I have an example dataset as presented below:

```
tc <- textConnection('
path           touchpoint  time
abc             A           1        
abc             A           2        
abc             B           3        
abc             C           4         
def             A           2       
def             B           3       
def             D           4        
def             C           5        
def             D           6 
ghi             A           1
ghi             A           2
ghi             A           3
ghi             C           4
jkl             A           5        
jkl             A           6        
jkl             B           7        
jkl             C           8     
mno             B           1        
mno             A           2        
mno             A           3       
mno             C           4 
pqr             A           1
pqr             C           2
test     "touchpoint A"     1
test     "touchpoint-B"     2
')

paths <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)
```

I would like to create paths overviews, and count the number of times a path occurs. The `touchpoints` are contactpoints that form the `path`. Each `path` is identified by a character (or set of characters), which is stated in the column `path`. For instance `path` abc contains touchpoint A,A,B and C. As output I would like to have an overview of the paths with all the different touchpoints, with their count.

There is no fixed width of this output table, since one path can have a great amount of different touchpoints. Therefore I would like to have the count in the first column. Two other constraints are that:

- The paths are created based on time, the touchpoints with the lowest time should always come first.
- If there is a touchpoint from the same instance subsequently (so A-A), than in the overview it should be presented as A, or more ideally A (2x)

I really have no idea where to start on this one..

The expected output for the example is:

```
freq           1                2               3       4       5
 2             A                B               C   
 2             A                C
 1             A                B               D       C       D
 1             B                A               C
 1            "touchpoint A"    "touchpoint-B"
```

The more ideal output would be:

```
freq           1                2               3       4       5
 2             A (2x)           B               C   
 1             A                B               D       C       D
 1             A (3x)           C
 1             B                A (2x)          C
 1             A (2x)           C
 1            "touchpoint A"    "touchpoint-B"
```

The column names 1 to N are chosen to indicate whether the touchpoint was first, second or Nth. Note that in the 'ideal' output, one journey more is presented, due to the fact that the journey for `ghi` and `pqr` for the first output provided is the same (A-A-C will become A-C there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short helper function using `rle()` and a bit of `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

foo <- function(x){
  r <- rle(as.character(x))
  short <- paste0(r$values, collapse="_")
  long  <- paste0(r$values, "(", r$lengths, ")", collapse="_")
  data.frame(short, long)
}

ddply(paths, .(path), function(x)foo(x$touchpoint))

  path                     short                            long
1  abc                     A_B_C                  A(2)_B(1)_C(1)
2  def                 A_B_D_C_D        A(1)_B(1)_D(1)_C(1)_D(1)
3  ghi                       A_C                       A(3)_C(1)
4  jkl                     A_B_C                  A(2)_B(1)_C(1)
5  mno                     B_A_C                  B(1)_A(2)_C(1)
6  pqr                       A_C                       A(1)_C(1)
7 test touchpoint A_touchpoint-B touchpoint A(1)_touchpoint-B(1)
```

---

This gets you most of the way there. You can count the number of occurrences using another `ddply()`, `tapply()` or similar. And you can convert the short form into a table with `strsplit()`.

Comment: Nice solution! Does the job and I am able to split both the short and long versions with strsplit() as suggested. Is there any way to easily incorporate a maximum of touchpoints for the long version? Righ now I can get a dataframe with thousands of rows and 100+ columns since there are 1 or 2 paths with 100+ touchpoints. Would be nice to incorporate a maximum of N columns

Comment: I think the question here is: is there a way to only chose the last N `values` (and their `lenghts`) from the `rle()` object. I specifically notice the last N values, since these are the most recent onces per path. Sounds like a new question to me :)